# Execute java code on cancel workflow in Knime

Tags: java, knime

I'm currently working with a few custom Knime nodes that interact with a separate Hadoop cluster, when cancelling a Knime workflow i basically want to be able to tell the cluster to kill the jobs it started. I'm thinking this would be a workflow-specific functionality rather than node-specific, so the nodes wouldn't be the place to implement this code.

Does anyone know how i could implement this ? I found something in the Knime documentation about a workflow manager, but i haven't seen any examples yet about extending its functionality. Any thought and resources regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the lovely Knime community over at http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-developers/performing-custom-actions-at-when-cancelling-a-workflow